# sending JSON object along with file using FormData in ajax call and accessing the json object in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to send json object along with a file in ajax call as follows

**Javascript**

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    var file_data = $('#imgFile').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    let jsonObj = {
        'label1':'value1'
    };
    form_data.append('file', file_data);
    form_data.append('json', jsonObj);//json object which I am trying to send
    $.ajax({
        url: 'uploader.php',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(php_script_response){
            console.log(php_script_response);
        }
    });
});
```

and in PHP I am able to retrieve the file sent in ajax call successfully but **I dont know how to access the json object sent along with that file**

**PHP**

```
<?php
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploadedFiles/1.' . $file_ext);
    echo $_POST['json'];
}
```

**please let me know how to retrive the json object in php**

Comment: what you see in `print_r($_POST)` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, note that you can only append binary data or a string through the `FormData.append()` method. Providing an object as you are means that `toString()` will be called on it, so the value will actually become `"[object Object]"`.

To fix this you'll need to manually `JSON.stringify` the object before you `append()` it:

```
let obj = {
    'label1':'value1'
};
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('json', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Then in your PHP you can deserialise the JSON using `json_decode()`.

However, it would be much simpler to just append the values to the `FormData` object directly. That way you don't need to manually serialize/deserialize anything:

```
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('label1', 'value1');
form_data.append('foo', 'bar');
```

Then in your PHP:

```
var label = $_POST['label'];
var foo = $_POST['foo'];
```

Comment: the json object which I mentioned in the above code is just dummy, actually object has many fields so I don't think appending each of them is a good idea,
I will use `JSON.stringify(obj)` and can you please let me know how to use json_decode in php to retrieve this json as I am a newbie ,

Comment: I'm no expert in PHP at all, hopefully the docs will tell you all you need to know: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'uploader.php',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data+"&json="+jsonObj,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(php_script_response){
        console.log(php_script_response);
    }
});
```

The PHPp code should then work with $_POST['json']

Comment: You cannot append binary form data with a string