# Is it possible to send form data and raw data at the same time?

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I have a create method to register a Game, and i want to send raw data as json and form data to upload a file at the same time.

This is my method in my controller:

```
exports.registerGame = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, description, employees, hours } = req.body;

  // Verify that the hours are valid and dont overlap
  const overlappingHours = hours.some((currentHour, currentIndex) => {
    return hours.slice(currentIndex + 1).some((nextHour) => {
      return (
        (currentHour.opening <= nextHour.opening &&
          nextHour.opening < currentHour.closing) ||
        (currentHour.opening < nextHour.closing &&
          nextHour.closing <= currentHour.closing) ||
        (nextHour.opening <= currentHour.opening &&
          currentHour.closing <= nextHour.closing)
      );
    });
  });

  if (overlappingHours) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      error: 'Range of hours are overlapping',
    });
  }

  if (!req.files) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`Please upload a file`, 400));
  }

  const file = req.files.file;

  // Make sure the image is a photo
  if (!file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse(`Please upload an image file`, 400));
  }

  // Check filesize
  if (file.size > process.env.MAX_FILE_UPLOAD) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(
        `Please upload an image less than ${process.env.MAX_FILE_UPLOAD}`,
        400
      )
    );
  }

  // Create custom filename
  file.name = `photo_${game._id}${path.parse(file.name).ext}`;

  file.mv(`${process.env.FILE_UPLOAD_PATH}/${file.name}`, async (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return next(new ErrorResponse(`Problem with file upload`, 500));
    }
  });

  const game = await Game.create({
    name,
    description,
    employees,
    hours,
    photo: file.name,
  });

  res.status(201).json({
    success: true,
    data: game,
  });
});
```

So if i send the request with the raw data tab active i my error `Please upload an image file` is triggered. But if send it with the form data tab open where i upload the photo, i get an error `Cannot read property of undefined (reading some)`

If not when i hit the request from my front end i will have to do a POST request to create a game with no photo, await for that game to be created, and the do a PUT request to another route to update the game and upload a file. But it might be a more efficient way with sending just one POST request. Any ideas?

Comment: Add the JSON as a field within the `FormData`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sending JSON object along with file using FormData in ajax call and accessing the json object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025970/sending-json-object-along-with-file-using-formdata-in-ajax-call-and-accessing-th)