# Angular file upload to Spring Boot fails with multipart boundary rejection

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload Angular form data to Spring Boot server.

Simply, in Spring Boot I accept:

```
data class Photo(
    val id: Long = 0L,
    val file: MultipartFile
)

data class PostRequest(
    @field:Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    val title: String,

    val photos: List<Photo> = mutableListOf()
)
```

via Controller:

```
fun createPost(@Valid @ModelAttribute postRequest: PostRequest)
```

In Angular I created this form:

```
this.postForm = this.fb.group({
   title: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],
   photos: this.fb.array([]),
});
```

When user uploads a photo I call these lines:

```
const photosArray = this.postForm.get("photos") as FormArray;
          
const newPhotoGroup = this.fb.group({
  id: "",
  file: event.target.result,
});
          
photosArray.push(newPhotoGroup);
```

Finally, I construct a form data object:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("title", this.postForm.get("title")?.value);
formData.append("photos", this.postForm.get("photos")?.value);
```

I use this function to post this form to API:

```
 postRequest<T>(url: string, body: any): Observable<HttpResponse<T>> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    });

    return this.http.post<T>(url, body, {
      headers,
      observe: "response",
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }
```

In developer tools I see this request:

[image]

Spring Boot complains:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Someone, enlighten me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`photos` form control is an array of objects, which is sent like that (as `[object Object]`) in the request, hence the error.

You need to loop the array and append each file:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("title", this.postForm.get("title")?.value);
// loop files and append them
this.postForm.get("photos")?.value.forEach((obj:any, i:number)=>{
    formData.append("photos", obj.file); // user property which has file:File
});
```

Also, when adding file to the array, make sure it has `File` type (`event.target.result` seems to be a string now, if so, use `event.target.file` or add a new property, for example 'uploadFile', and add that to `formData` later):

```
const newPhotoGroup = this.fb.group({
    id: "",
    file: event.target.result, // this should be File from event.target.file
  });
```

*if you want to include `id`, i.e. custom file data, along with the file, it cannot go along with the file in the same formData key*

You could use id instead of filename:

```
formData.append("photos", obj.file, obj.id)
```

or adapt the upload process something like this: [sending JSON object along with file using FormData in ajax call and accessing the json object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025970/sending-json-object-along-with-file-using-formdata-in-ajax-call-and-accessing-th)

Finally, make the reqeuest without `content-type headers`, the `FormData` will handle it:

```
return this.http.post<T>(url, body, {
    observe: "response",
    withCredentials: true,
  });
```